# How to get all featured sellers with dokan

Tags: wordpress, dokan

Is it possible to get all featured sellesrs with dokan (wordpress plugin)?

I found only this option, which gets all sellers, but in returned data, there is no mention if the store is featured or not.

```
$sellers = dokan_get_sellers();
foreach ($sellers['users'] as $seller) {
    $store_info = dokan_get_store_info($seller->ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time you want to know exactly what a functions does and how it does whatever it does, just follow the term. Searching for dokan_get_sellers on all files of the plugin takes us to where the function is written and there we see we can pass an array of arguments to it. One of the arguments it accepts is "featured" and it expects a yes or no for value. So, this is what we can do:

```
$args = array( 'featured' => 'yes' );
$sellers = dokan_get_sellers( $args );
```

I did not test it, but it should be right.